# Empty rules in snortrules snapshot

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, rules, snort, intrusion-detection

I configured to install Snort on my Ubuntu 12.04 which also included Barnyard2 and BASE installation. I am using the downloadable rules on Snort's website which requires me to sign up there to get the `oinkcode`.

But however, after I investigate the rules that I had extracted to `/etc/snort/rules` directory where all the rules are, all those rules are just plain empty. 
Here is one of the rules look like

```
# Copyright 2001-2013 Sourcefire, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# This file contains (i) proprietary rules that were created, tested and certified by
# Sourcefire, Inc. (the "VRT Certified Rules") that are distributed under the VRT
# Certified Rules License Agreement (v 2.0), and (ii) rules that were created by
# Sourcefire and other third parties (the "GPL Rules") that are distributed under the
# GNU General Public License (GPL), v2.
# 
# The VRT Certified Rules are owned by Sourcefire, Inc. The GPL Rules were created
# by Sourcefire and other third parties. The GPL Rules created by Sourcefire are
# owned by Sourcefire, Inc., and the GPL Rules not created by Sourcefire are owned by
# their respective creators. Please see http://www.snort.org/snort/snort-team/ for a
# list of third party owners and their respective copyrights.
# 
# In order to determine what rules are VRT Certified Rules or GPL Rules, please refer
# to the VRT Certified Rules License Agreement (v2.0).
#
#------------
# SCAN RULES
#------------
```

Can anyone help me to point out what is wrong with these rules? 
I downloaded the `snortrules-snapshot-2970.tar.gz` with the oinckode I got which used the `snort-2.9.7.0`. Are there any solutions? I could post the snort configuration file (snort.conf) too if needed, I don't know how to make it shorter in post though.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the files are empty.  When the rules were moved from the old category structure to the new category structure the old files were kept there for backwards compatibility.

Keep looking